# ui-router change state via a URL address?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm having trouble transitioning to another view state when I only have the full URL path. The ui-router says to use `$state.transitionTo` or `$state.go` but those require the state name.

I tried to change the current URL using `$location.url(path)` but nothing happens.

Is `$location.url(path)` the correct way, and something is wrong with my setup or is there another way to do it?

Here is my configuration for the home page:

```
$stateProvider.state(
    {
        name:       'home',
        url:        '^/',
        templateUrl: "/home.html"
    }
);
```

Here is my config for the app.

```
cgTag.App.Config.Config = function($httpProvider, $locationProvider, $sce)
{
    // Let CakePHP see $http requests as AJAX
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
    // use HTML5 non-hash URLs
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');

    // add all the CDN domains to the white list so that URLs are not blocked by Angular.
    var cdn = cgTag.AppData["Domain"].replace(/^www\./, "http://s*.") + "/**";
    $sce.resourceUrlWhitelist(['self', cdn]);
};
cgTag.Angular.config(['$httpProvider', '$locationProvider', '$sceDelegateProvider', cgTag.App.Config.Config]);
```

If the current browser url is http://www.cgtag.com/movies then calling `$location.url("/")` should go to the home page, but nothing happens.

Comment: Can you show the configuration for `$urlRouterProvider` and `$stateProvier` and the URL you are trying to navigate to?

Comment: Remove the '^' from your state URL. The URLs are just strings not regexes.

Comment: @Sly_cardinal nope this didn't fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to call `$scope.$apply()` after calling `$location.url(path)`.

Could be because the code was in a `keydown` event handler.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `$location.path()` instead `$location.url()`